# Spring XD ExecutionContext Deserializer

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

I have a job module with an isolated classpath.  I have added a POJO form the isolated context to a step execution context which gets serialized.  When this context is deserialized, an exception is thrown because the class cannot be loaded since the default execution context deserializer uses the app context classloader instead of the parent first classloader.  The work around is to add the jars with the POJO into the main classpath instead of the isolated classpath.  Is there a way to keep these in the isolated classpath and use the ParentFirstClassloader?

Stack Trace

```html
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: my.meta.JobMetadata
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:79)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:70)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.putCurrentEntryIntoMap(MapConverter.java:110)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.populateMap(MapConverter.java:98)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.populateMap(MapConverter.java:92)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.unmarshal(MapConverter.java:87)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
        ... 60 more

and 

Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=egress-transfer at state=myjob.step with exception
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:171)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:141)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowStep.doExecute(FlowStep.java:90)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: my.meta.JobMetadata : my.meta.JobMetadata
---- Debugging information ----
message             : my.meta.JobMetadata
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : my.meta.JobMetadata
class               : java.util.HashMap
required-type       : java.util.HashMap
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter
path                : /map/entry[2]/my.meta.JobMetadata
line number         : -1
version             : 1.4.7
-------------------------------
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
```

Comment: Just to confirm, who's deserializing the POJO?  Is it the admin node for use by the UI or is it the job?

Comment: Could you share the stacktrace please? thanks!

Comment: It is the job, usually during a restart of the job.

Comment: Taking this conversation into the related Jira issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2486